# Import JSON file in .ts and compile it with SWC

Tags: swc-compiler

I have a typescript file that import a json file like this:

```
import DefaultMapping from "./default.json";
```

It compile with SWC like this in the js file:

```
var _defaultJson = require("./default.json");
```

However, SWC does not copy the JSON file in the build folder. Therefore, i have an error when I run the js file:

```
Error: Cannot find module './default.json'
```

Can someone help me please?

*EDIT: I solve it partially by using `require` instead of `import` in the ts file and also using the `--copy-files` swc option. However, I still would like to NOT use `require` and use `import` instead if someone has an idea*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by using the `--copy-files` options.

Here is my command:
`swc ./src --out-dir dist --copy-files`